# Как добавить, корректно работающий JScrollPane к JTextArea?(Java,Swing)

Tags: java, swing, gui

Не могу разобраться с одной проблемой, у меня в приложении есть форма JTextArea и к ней прикреплен JScrollPane. Но как сделать рабочую прокрутку я не знаю, когда поле JtextArea полностью заполняется текстом,то оно начинает увеличивать свой размер по вертикали и заезжает на прогресс бар и кнопки расположенные ниже. Хотелось бы исправить данную ситуацию.

Вот код

```
    package main.java.view;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class ShopQueueGUIApp {

        public static final int W_WIDTH = 540;
        public static final int W_HEIGHT = 500;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            JFrame mainForm = new JFrame("Queue Shop v0.3 alpha");
            mainForm.setSize(W_WIDTH,W_HEIGHT); // размер окна
            mainForm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // закрывать приложение нажатием крестика
            mainForm.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // расположить окно по центру экрана
            mainForm.setResizable(false); // запретить изменение размеров окна
            mainForm.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); // Слой

            // Текстовая информация о работе приложения
            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            JLabel infoLabel = new JLabel("Данная программа моделирует");
            JLabel infoLabel2 = new JLabel("очередь покупателей в кассы");
            JLabel infoLabel3 = new JLabel("магазина.");
            JLabel infoLabel4 = new JLabel("Каждую минуту заходит или не");
            JLabel infoLabel5 = new JLabel("заходит один покупатель, это");
            JLabel infoLabel6 = new JLabel("определяется случайным образом.");
            JLabel infoLabel7 = new JLabel("Покупатель также случайно выбирает");
            JLabel infoLabel8 = new JLabel("одну из пяти касс магазина,");
            JLabel infoLabel9 = new JLabel("обслуживается на протяжении");
            JLabel infoLabel10 = new JLabel("от одной до трех минут, и затем");
            JLabel infoLabel11 = new JLabel("покидает очередь.");
            JLabel infoLabel12 = new JLabel("Данный процесс пошагово");
            JLabel infoLabel13 = new JLabel("отображается в окне справа.");
            JLabel infoLabel14 = new JLabel("Задайте время моделирования");
            JLabel infoLabel15 = new JLabel("(по умолчанию - 30 минут)");
            JLabel infoLabel16 = new JLabel("Нажмите кнопку \"+1 минута\"");
            JLabel infoLabel17 = new JLabel("чтобы увеличить текущее время");
            JLabel infoLabel18 = new JLabel("на 1 минуту.");
            JLabel infoLabel19 = new JLabel("Нажмите кнопку \"Стоп\"");
            JLabel infoLabel20 = new JLabel("чтобы остановить процесс");
            JLabel infoLabel21 = new JLabel("моделирования.");
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        // Расположение текстовой инфы
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        mainForm.add(infoLabel,new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel2,new GridBagConstraints(0,1,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel3,new GridBagConstraints(0,2,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel4,new GridBagConstraints(0,3,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel5,new GridBagConstraints(0,4,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel6,new GridBagConstraints(0,5,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel7,new GridBagConstraints(0,6,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel8,new GridBagConstraints(0,7,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel9,new GridBagConstraints(0,8,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel10,new GridBagConstraints(0,9,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel11,new GridBagConstraints(0,10,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel12,new GridBagConstraints(0,11,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel13,new GridBagConstraints(0,12,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel14,new GridBagConstraints(0,13,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel15,new GridBagConstraints(0,14,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel16,new GridBagConstraints(0,15,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel17,new GridBagConstraints(0,16,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel18,new GridBagConstraints(0,17,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel19,new GridBagConstraints(0,18,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel20,new GridBagConstraints(0,19,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                                                        GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(infoLabel21,new GridBagConstraints(0,20,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        // Поле ввода времени и кнопка для его установки
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        JTextField endTimeLineField = new JTextField();
        JButton setTimeButton = new JButton("Задать время");
        // Отображение вышеописанных элементов
        mainForm.add(endTimeLineField,new GridBagConstraints(0,21,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(setTimeButton,new GridBagConstraints(0,22,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        // Консоль вывода
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        JTextArea console = new JTextArea(20,1);
        //console.setEditable(false);
        console.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        console.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(console);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        JLabel consLabel = new JLabel("Консоль вывода:");
        // Отображение вышеописанных элементов
        mainForm.add(console,new GridBagConstraints(1,1,1,24,0.0,0.0,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(consLabel,new GridBagConstraints(1,0,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(scroll,new GridBagConstraints(2,1,1,20,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        // Кнопки управления роессом моделирования
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        JButton stepButton = new JButton("+1 Минута");
        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Остановить моделирование");
        // Отображение вышеописанных элементов
        mainForm.add(stopButton,new GridBagConstraints(1,23,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        mainForm.add(stepButton,new GridBagConstraints(0,23,1,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        // Прогресс бар
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        JProgressBar timeLineBar = new JProgressBar();
        timeLineBar.setStringPainted(true);
        timeLineBar.setMinimum(0);
        timeLineBar.setMaximum(100);
        timeLineBar.setValue(25);
        // Отображение вышеописанных элементов
        mainForm.add(timeLineBar,new GridBagConstraints(1,22,2,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(3,1,1,1),0,0));
        // Метка для прогресс-бара
        JLabel progressLabel = new JLabel("Прогресс:");
        // Отображение вышеописанных элементов
        mainForm.add(progressLabel,new GridBagConstraints(1,21,2,1,0.0,0.9,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(1,70,1,1),0,0));
        //--------------------------------------------------------------

        mainForm.pack();
        mainForm.setVisible(true); // включить видимость окна

    }
}
```

Вот как все это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, оказывается, что после:

```
JTextArea console = new JTextArea(20,20);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(console);
```

добавлять на форму нужно только scroll.
Т.е убираем строку:

```
mainForm.add(console,new GridBagConstraints(1,1,1,24,0.0,0.0,GridBagConstraints.NORTH,
            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0));
```